# How to not mount a partition in fstab file on boot but rather on click on shortcut in nautilus?

Tags: mount, systemd

I am mounting a samba share using fstab file as:

```
//192.168.2.2/Expansion     /samba/raspberry/   cifs    x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10s,_netdev,users,nofail,uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/home/edward/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm    0   0
```

but the thing with this entry is `systemd` will try to mount it even if I don't need it.
So is there any option of mount command for fstab file that will mount this only on first access by shortcut in nautilus?

I am using latest Arch Linux with Gnome 3.18

**Please note: I am taking this question with samba share but the question is about option we can use in fstab file**

Comment: add *noauto* to fstab

Comment: Sounds like a job for the automounter.

Comment: And [here's the relevant instruction](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs).

Comment: Did you try taking out x-systemd.automount?

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tested this with samba, but it's probably the same as with a local filesystem.

you need to change edit `fstab` line to include the two options `x-systemd.automount,noauto` and then it will not be mounted automatically, it will only be mounted when accessed. to make it active instantly, instead of having to reboot, do the following:

```
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

and then both, or one, of the following:

```
  sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
  sudo systemctl restart local-fs.target
```